# Как правильно организовать работу с удаленным сервером средствами Pycharm

Tags: git, pycharm

Имеется проект на гитлабе. Python-интерпретатор находится на сервере. Я склонировал себе на локальную машину проект с гита, средствами  Pycharm организовал автодеплой на сервер. И запускал проект на сервере. При переключении на другую ветку гита на локальной машине, на сервере эти изменения отразились не полностью: то есть состояние файлов и папок на сервере такое, каким оно стало на момент первичной синхронизации с состоянием проекта на локальной машине. Отсюда и возникли проблемы. Как можно решить данную задачу, чтобы автоматическое переключение между ветками гита на локальной машине отражалось и на состоянии проекта на сервере?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сказал, что эта фича.

Рабочий сервер должен быть синхронизирован со стабильной веткой (типа release), a не прыгать туда-сюда.

Сервер разработки можно запустить локально в докере.

Если локально нет сетевого доступа куда-то/откуда-то -- пробросить.

Если локально мало памяти -- `rsync ...` -- на хоткей повесить

Comment: я говорю в общем (Pycharm не использую)

Comment: Вы ещё забыли сетевые ФС рассмотреть: NFS, Samba, SSHFS, ...

Comment: @0andriy, сетевые ФС сильно зависят от качества сети; пробовал, не подошли.